# Cloud not run my Vue CLI App after update Node.js 12 to 14

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

I want you help to get my Vue CLI App runing in development server of my local environment.
I can not get the App runing after update Node.js 12 to 14 because I am getting an error - attached screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNaPX.jpg)

My environment include:
Node.js v14.17.1 x64
Windows 10 x64
Version 91.0.4472.114

```
├── @fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3
├── @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.2.35
├── @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@5.15.3
├── @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome@0.1.10
├── @popperjs/core@2.9.2
├── @vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.4.6
├── @vue/cli-plugin-router@4.4.6
├── @vue/cli-service@4.5.13
├── @vue/eslint-config-prettier@6.0.0
├── babel-eslint@10.1.0
├── bootstrap@4.6.0
├── core-js@3.15.2
├── css-loader@4.3.0
├── eslint-plugin-import@2.23.4
├── eslint-plugin-node@11.1.0
├── eslint-plugin-prettier@3.4.0
├── eslint-plugin-promise@4.3.1
├── eslint-plugin-standard@4.1.0
├── eslint-plugin-vue@6.2.2
├── eslint@6.8.0
├── firebase-admin@9.10.0
├── firebase@8.7.0
├── jquery@3.6.0
├── moment@2.29.1
├── node-sass@6.0.1
├── npm@7.19.1
├── popper.js@1.16.1
├── prettier@1.19.1
├── sass-loader@12.1.0
├── serve@12.0.0
├── style-loader@1.3.0
├── vue-eslint-parser@7.7.2
├── vue-fragment@1.5.2
├── vue-router@3.5.2
├── vue-template-compiler@2.6.14
├── vue@2.6.14
├── webpack-dev-server@3.11.2
└── webpack@5.0.0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTUMK.jpg)

Comment: Post relevant information as text and not as image.

Comment: Use the [edit] functionality to add further informations to your question, and not the comment section.